# Row_number() behaviour change in H2 1.4.195

Tags: sql, h2

When executing this script in H2 v 1.4.194

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS chrs;

CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE chrs as (
SELECT CHAR(X) as chr from SYSTEM_RANGE(48,90)
);

SELECT
        row_number() OVER () as row_number,
        chr
FROM
        chrs
WHERE
    chr ~ '[A-Z]';
```

I get this (as expected)

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
etc..
```

in

1.4.195 i get this:

```
18  A
19  B
20  C
etc..
```

18 being the row number for A in the chrs table. Is this a H2 bug or a deliberate change in behaviour?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This is also in 1.4.195 so it's a bug in a stable release, honestly that's quite troubling, hoping someone can tell me it's actually intended behaviour.

Comment: You probably get more attention from the H2 developers if you post that in their forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h2-database

Comment: Damn, that's definitely a bug and quite a big one. Very troubling indeed, let's see how fast it will be handled. Something like this never should've happened definitely not in a stable version. High chance for stuff to break for some unlucky people...

Comment: This was fixed https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/600 don't know if you're `Michael2109` but even if not you deserve the credit. If you like you can self answer this question, I will upvote if you do that. Took ~7 days between submission and fix, overall quite reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, Michael posted the github issue on my behalf, so should we stick to 1.4.194 until 196 goes stable or have you re-issued 195?

Comment: For reference I can confirm this is fixed in H2 1.4.199.